# Deleting files on Filezilla very slow compared to hosting

Tags: ftp, web-hosting

I have noticed that when deleting a folder on Filezilla it can take a very long time if the folder has subfolders with many files, example I deleted a .git repository / folder and it took Filezilla 15 minutes.

However, with a hosting account and their FTP manager you can delete a folder and it is immediately removed including all files and sub folders.

Why the difference. Is there a setting for Filezilla that can speed this up.

Comment: One possible answer is latency - even if the hosting manager is using FTP the latency is zero, so it doesn't have to wait so long to issue commands. Alternately it might be manipulating the file system with shell commands which are more efficient.

Comment: We found a way around by using remote desktop services for mass deleting files. Not a real solution for Filezilla, but a possible way to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this thread:
https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=6186, 
it seems it is because Filezilla can only delete a folder if it is empty, so it has to delete each file one-by-one first, rather than just deleting the folder all at once.